# Extend Kendo Mobile view and use declaratively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, javascript-framework, kendo-mobile

I want to extend the Kendo Mobile view and use them declartively like this:

```
   <div id="home" data-role="extendedview" data-layout="default">
        Hello Mobile World!
   </div>
```

Then in the extended view, I want to run code in the init and show events automatically. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to fire a common function for all the views' init and show events using just one hook?

Comment: Yes and I am already inheriting classes, but require me to always set the data-init and data-show all the time with the native view. I would like data-init, data-show, and other data-* to be implicit/automatic with the extended view so even the declarative is shorter as well as base hooks to fire.

Comment: Can you show some code? I can try to help you extend it.